# Manually place a toolbar Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

My QMainWindow contains three different windows.
I would like to display three different toolbars. One for each window.
For now I display a toolbar but I can not place it just above my windows.
I wanted to know if it was possible?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent) {
    //here I declared a widget and my three windows.
    QToolBar *toolBar= addToolBar("window");
    addLine=new QAction("Add Line",this);
    removeLine=new QAction("Remove line",this);
    removeAll=new QAction("Remove all",this);
    toolBar->addAction(addLine);
    toolBar->addAction(removeLine);
    toolBar->addAction(removeAll);
}
```

Comment: 1 QMainWindow with 3 windows or does it mean 1 QMainWindow with 3 widgets?

Comment: 1 QMainWindow with 3 widgets :) I managed to solve my problem by putting the toolbar in a QVBoxLayout. This contains the toolbar and a widget.

Comment: This would've been my answer. There is a special area to place `QToolBar` in `QMainWindow` which makes them (un-)dockable. However, a `QToolBar` can be used like any other `QWidget` and added to anywhere where `QWidget`s are accepted.